# Image container taking more space than it should

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

How can I remove the empty space from the image container (blue)?
I need it to be compatible with ie11.

I don't want to hardcode the width/height of the container because images can be different aspect ratios and sizes.

```css
main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.video {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    max-height: 5em;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.video .image {
    background: blue;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.video .image img {
    max-width: 20vw;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="video">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="https://placehold.it/300/200">
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>title</p>
            <p>description</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Add `min-height: 100%` to `img`

Comment: and why you need the image inside the div?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I need it inside a div because I need to separate it from the right content I edited my code to be closer to what im using

Comment: @YTG I didn't see any change adding that

Comment: the best you can do is this: https://jsfiddle.net/t3upc4bL/

Comment: not to .image but img. I inspected with chrome dev tools and it works. I can post the photo below if you'd like.

Comment: @TemaniAfif that doesn't seem work on ie11

Comment: try this: https://jsfiddle.net/t3upc4bL/1/

Comment: @TemaniAfif Still doesnt :(

Comment: The max-width of the image seems to be responsible for the parent div width

Answer (score 0):

I find a strange thing: If we download the image and load it from the same server as the test page like this `<img src="picture/200.png">`, the following CSS code works well in IE:

```
main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.video {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    height: 5em;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.video .image {
    height: 100%;
}

.video .image img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

I serve the image and the test page through localhost, you can see the result:
[image]

If you still want to use the online link as image source, you can try the following code without flexbox which can work well in IE:

```css
main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.video img {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="video">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300/200">
    <div class="content">
      <p>title</p>
      <p>description</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: @TheGamerX Please check my edited answer. I find some workarounds which you can refer to.